# Change an Angular component's variable by passing it from the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm working on an Angular (8) application and I have a list of items which I iterate using *ngFor in the HTML like this:

```
        <div *ngFor="let item of someList">
          <app-template [item]="item"
                        (deleteItem)="deleteFromList($event, someList)"></app-template>
        </div>
```

What I want to do is to delete one item from the list using the deleteFromList() function. I have found a method for delete that I quite like, but other alternatives can be presented. Here is how my function looks like:

```
  deleteFromList(forDeletion, myList) {
      myList = myList.filter(item => item !== forDeletion);                 
  }
```

As you see, I am passing the list as a parameter to this function (instead of accessing the list from the component where I am now). I do this because I want to call this function for another delete operation for *another list* that I have in the same file, so I must know not only which element to delete, but from which of the lists.

The problem is that passing the list from HTML and change that *parameter list variable* will not change the actual variable from the component which I am iterating on. Is there a clean and ethical solution to this? And why isn't that list variable changing if I change the *param list variable*?

Thank you! :)

Comment: As you iterate through `someList` in your template I suppose that you have that variable populated in your component, so there is no need to pass it to the delete function.

Comment: @standby954 As I mentioned, I will call the delete function for more lists ( I have 4 lists in my component) and I want to avoid making 4 functions like (deleteFromListOne, deleteFromListTwo...)

Comment: Ah, ok sorry I've missed that part. Your logic is almost good. I would use something like this: `const el = myList.findIndex(item => item.id === forDeletion);` to find the corresponding item to be deleted (here I used id but you should adapt this to your own logic) and then use splice to remove it from the array: `myList.splice(el, 1);`

Comment: ok, that worked. Problem solved, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

standby954's answer solved my problem. Seems that I can not reasign the list passed as a param but only to modify it.
Solution:

```
const el = myList.findIndex(item => item.id === forDeletion);
myList.splice(el, 1);
```